# Question about the verb 失う

Tags: conjugations, colloquial-language, dialects, volitional-form, kansai-ben

I came across the sentence from a Manga which I think it would be Kansai-dialect form.

> なんや　ようわからんうちに気をうし**の**うてしまったが...

I think that it would be volitional form so I have looked it up and found that it is 「うし**なお**う」which is different.

I would like to know is there any concept or rule behind the transforming of 「なお」 to 「の」.  Or is it just a slur?

Comment: `うしのうてしまったが` -- へえ・・漫画のセリフですかね？「うしなって」は「うしのうて」になってるのに、「しまった」はそのままなのね・・

Answer (score 2):

> Kansai-daialect: **なんや**　**よう**　**わからん** うちに気を **うしのうて** しまったが...
> Standard Japanese: **なんだか**　**よく**　**わからない** うちに気を **うしなって** しまったが...
> *Although I fainted myself while I wasn't aware of it better* ...

<del>I'm sorry I don't know the precise concept or rules behind the transformings.</del>

---

## EDIT

In the explanation [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/is-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%81%9F-the-same-as-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-what-is-the-grammatical-rule-behind-this), the example of the questioner can be read as if it is the relationship between ウ[音便]｛おんびん｝ in the Kansai dialect and 促音便｛そくおんびん｝ in the standard Japanese, but as shown below, there are examples conforming to this rule and examples not conforming to this rule.
Looking at the examples listed, even if a word in standard Japanse of the past tense form has the same sound as the word to that the rule can be applied, it is understood that this rule cannot be applied unless the ending form of the present tense of the word is "う".

現在形　促音便　　ウ音便
　　　 Standard　 Kansai
　　　 Japanese　 dialect

> 失｛うしな｝う　 失｛うしな｝った 　失｛うしの｝うた

会う　　会｛あ｝った　　会｛お｝うた
合う　　合｛あ｝った　　合｛お｝うた
有**る**　　有｛あ｝った　　<del>有｛お｝うた</del>
仕舞う　仕舞｛しま｝った　仕舞｛しも｝うた　《片付けた》
終う　　終｛しま｝った　　終｛しも｝うた　　《片付けた》
しまう　しまった　しもうた　《しくじった》
買う　　買｛か｝った　　買｛こ｝うた
勝**つ**　　勝｛か｝った　　<del>[勝]｛こ｝うた</del>
擦**る**　　擦｛す｝った　　<del>擦｛す｝うた</del>　　《使い果たす》
吸う　　吸｛す｝った　　吸｛す｝うた
縫う　　縫｛ぬ｝った　　縫｛ぬ｝うた
塗**る**　　塗｛ぬ｝った　　<del>塗｛ぬ｝うた</del>
叶う　　叶｛かな｝った　　叶｛かの｝うた
適う　　適｛かな｝った　　適｛かの｝うた
這う　　這｛は｝った　　這｛ほ｝うた
貼**る**　　貼｛は｝った　　<del>貼｛ほ｝うた</del>
張**る**　　張｛は｝った　　<del>張｛ほ｝うた</del>
舞う　　舞｛ま｝った　　舞｛も｝うた　　《踊｛おど｝った》
待**つ**　　待｛ま｝った　　<del>待｛も｝うた</del>
違う　　違｛ちが｝った　　違｛ちご｝うた
庇う　　庇｛かば｝った　　庇｛かぼ｝うた

---

## EDIT 2

Explaining the relationship between "失｛うしの｝うて" and "失{うしな}って" by imitating the explanation [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/is-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%81%9F-the-same-as-%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-what-is-the-grammatical-rule-behind-this) it will be as follows.

"失{うしな}う" is a "ワ行｛ぎょう｝五段｛ごだん｝活用｛かつよう｝動詞｛どうし｝ *w-sound godan conjugation verb*", so it has a stem ending with the "[渡り音]｛わたりおん｝ *glide*" or "半母音｛はんぼいん｝ *semivowel*" with "w": "ushinaw-", and underwent different developments in "関西地方｛かんさいちほう｝ *Kansai region*" and "関東地方｛かんとうちほう｝ *Kanto region*" regarding "語尾変化｛ごびへんか｝ *inflection*". In Kanto region, the "w" was interpreted as a consonant, and was used to trigger gemination (a.k.a. 促音便｛そくおんびん｝) in 連用形｛れんようけい｝ or in past tense:

> ushinaw-te → ushinatte 失｛うしな｝って; ushinaw-ta → ushinatta 失｛うしな｝った.

On the other hand, in Kansai region, the "w" was turned into "u" (high back vowel), and then underwent further change of vowels (k.a. ウ音便｛おんびん｝):

> ushinaw-te → ushinaute → ushinoute 失｛うしの｝うて; ushinaw-ta → ushinauta → ushinouta 失｛うしの｝うた.

In addition, the dialect used in the Kanto region has been regarded as the standard Japanese language. Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language#Modern_Japanese) "Edo (now Tokyo) developed into the largest city in Japan, and the Edo-area dialect became standard Japanese."

If you read the above explanation carefully, you can see the reason why only the verbs ending with "う", that is, "ワ行五段活用動詞 *w-sound godan conjugation verbs*" conform to the 促音便 and ウ音便 rule, among the examples I mentioned in EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

As mackygoo mentions in his answer, it is used only when the verb in dictionary form ends with う. However, it is incorrect to say this is Kansai dialect, as this is used in many different dialects. Also, what is strange in your example sentence is that しまった should also change to しもうた. It might be that the speaker feels uncomfortable saying it twice in a row (becaus of the two long diphtongs); in Kyushu dialect that I am used to, it is common to only say it on the last or a verb-pair, e.g. 買ってしもうた instead of こうてしもうた, but both variants for sure exist.

Also, a word not mentioned in mackygoos list of examples is 言{ゆ}う →　言{ゆ}うて (instead of 言{い}って) which has become quite typical of Kansai dialect and is used among youngsters as well. In Northern Kyushu I would say that 言{ゆ}って is more common.

This conjugational variety (うしのうた etc) is used in the following dialects:
近畿方言{きんきほうげん}（関西弁{かんさいべん}）, 岐阜西濃{ぎふせいのう}, 北陸方言{ほくりくほうげん}, 越後方言{えちごほうげん}, 諸県弁{もろかたべん}と鹿児島弁{かごしまべん}を除{のぞ}き全九州弁{ぜんきゅうしゅうべん}

You should be aware though that there are regional differences as to in which sociolects it is being used. For example in Hakata region (Northern Kyushu) it is quite uncommon for young people to use it, but it also varies a lot if you live in the city or on the country-side.